# Reference the current node in a document tree, which is stored in a variable

Tags: variables, xpath, xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0

I have a stylesheet in which I loop through a Day-Element.
For each day, I need to get a value from another XML-document, which i have inside a parameter, referenced with $ArtStat.

If I use the filter as a fixed value of 2022-10-11, it works fine

```
<xsl:for-each select="Day">
    <QtyOut><xsl:value-of select="$ArtStat/ECRArtStat/Days/Day[Date='2022-10-11']/QtyOut" /></QtyOut>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I need to use the filter as a dynamic value (the content of the current node), and that doesnt work (the result in this case is that this select gives back an empty String ""

```
<xsl:for-each select="Day">
    <QtyOut><xsl:value-of select="$ArtStat/ECRArtStat/Days/Day[Date=current()]/QtyOut" /></QtyOut>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I tried it with current() or 'current()', with ., with self:node(), anything didnt work at all
I guess there is a simple solution with it, but I can't find it. I could use XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 with Saxon 9

The explanation above is a simplification of my issue. Cause actually what I need is: For each day on my XML document, I need to check the QtyOut-value inside another document and I need to sum them to one value. So something like this:

```
sum($ArtStat/ECRArtStat/Days/Day[Date=<Nodeset of the days>]/QtyOut)
```

but this I couldn't solve directly with XSL, so I try to set a variable first, and after sum the content, like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="QtyOutList">
   <xsl:for-each select="Day">
       <QtyOut><xsl:value-of select="$ArtStat/ECRArtStat/Days/Day[Date=current()]/QtyOut" /></QtyOut>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="sum($QtyOutList/QtyOut)" />
```

This does work if I use a fixed value for the date, but not with current(),....

Source XML (the source doc define for which days we need to get the values):

```
<Columns>
  <Column type="pastWeek">
    <WeekNo>40</WeekNo>
    <Year>2022</Year>
    <StartDay>2022-10-03</StartDay>
  </Column>
  <Column type="currentWeek">
    <WeekNo>41</WeekNo>
    <Year>2022</Year>
    <StartDay>2022-10-10</StartDay>
    <Day>2022-10-10</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-11</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-12</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-13</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-14</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-15</Day>
  </Column>
</Columns>
```

Referenced XML as a variable (where I need to get the QtyOut value from):

```
<ECRArtStat>
  <Days>
    <Day>
      <Date>2022-10-13</Date>
      <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
      <QtyOut>0</QtyOut>
    </Day>
    <Day>
      <Date>2022-10-12</Date>
      <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
      <QtyOut>0</QtyOut>
    </Day>
    <Day>
      <Date>2022-10-11</Date>
      <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
      <QtyOut>5</QtyOut>
     </Day>
     <Day>
       <Date>2022-10-10</Date>
       <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
       <QtyOut>4</QtyOut>
     </Day>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Column[Day]">
    <xsl:comment>Sum {sum($ArtStat/ECRArtStat/Days/Day[Date = current()/Day]/QtyOut)}</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:param name="ArtStat">
<ECRArtStat>
  <Days>
    <Day>
      <Date>2022-10-13</Date>
      <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
      <QtyOut>0</QtyOut>
    </Day>
    <Day>
      <Date>2022-10-12</Date>
      <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
      <QtyOut>0</QtyOut>
    </Day>
    <Day>
      <Date>2022-10-11</Date>
      <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
      <QtyOut>5</QtyOut>
     </Day>
     <Day>
       <Date>2022-10-10</Date>
       <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
       <QtyOut>4</QtyOut>
     </Day>
  </Days>
</ECRArtStat>
  </xsl:param>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

against an input of e.g.

```
<Columns>
  <Column type="pastWeek">
    <WeekNo>40</WeekNo>
    <Year>2022</Year>
    <StartDay>2022-10-03</StartDay>
  </Column>
  <Column type="currentWeek">
    <WeekNo>41</WeekNo>
    <Year>2022</Year>
    <StartDay>2022-10-10</StartDay>
    <Day>2022-10-10</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-11</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-12</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-13</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-14</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-15</Day>
  </Column>
</Columns>
```

the result is e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Columns>
  <Column type="pastWeek">
    <WeekNo>40</WeekNo>
    <Year>2022</Year>
    <StartDay>2022-10-03</StartDay>
  </Column>
  <!--Sum 9--><Column type="currentWeek">
    <WeekNo>41</WeekNo>
    <Year>2022</Year>
    <StartDay>2022-10-10</StartDay>
    <Day>2022-10-10</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-11</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-12</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-13</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-14</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-15</Day>
  </Column>
</Columns>
```

meaning a sum is computed based on the reference values.

As you pretend to ask questions about XSLT 3 but don't understand the use of text value templates or `xsl:next-match`, [here is an example](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22Column%5BDay%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%20%7C%20node%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSum%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22sum%28%24ArtStat%2FECRArtStat%2FDays%2FDay%5BDate%20%3D%20current%28%29%2FDay%5D%2FQtyOut%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FSum%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22ArtStat%22%3E%0D%0A%3CECRArtStat%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CDays%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDate%3E2022-10-13%3C%2FDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQtyIn%3E0%3C%2FQtyIn%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQtyOut%3E0%3C%2FQtyOut%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDate%3E2022-10-12%3C%2FDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQtyIn%3E0%3C%2FQtyIn%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQtyOut%3E0%3C%2FQtyOut%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDate%3E2022-10-11%3C%2FDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQtyIn%3E0%3C%2FQtyIn%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQtyOut%3E5%3C%2FQtyOut%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3CDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CDate%3E2022-10-10%3C%2FDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQtyIn%3E0%3C%2FQtyIn%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CQtyOut%3E4%3C%2FQtyOut%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2FDays%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FECRArtStat%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3CColumns%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CColumn%20type%3D%22pastWeek%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CWeekNo%3E40%3C%2FWeekNo%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CYear%3E2022%3C%2FYear%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CStartDay%3E2022-10-03%3C%2FStartDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2FColumn%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CColumn%20type%3D%22currentWeek%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CWeekNo%3E41%3C%2FWeekNo%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CYear%3E2022%3C%2FYear%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CStartDay%3E2022-10-10%3C%2FStartDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CDay%3E2022-10-10%3C%2FDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CDay%3E2022-10-11%3C%2FDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CDay%3E2022-10-12%3C%2FDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CDay%3E2022-10-13%3C%2FDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CDay%3E2022-10-14%3C%2FDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CDay%3E2022-10-15%3C%2FDay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2FColumn%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FColumns%3E&input-type=XML) using `xsl:value-of`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Column[Day]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <Sum>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum($ArtStat/ECRArtStat/Days/Day[Date = current()/Day]/QtyOut)"/>
      </Sum>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:param name="ArtStat">
<ECRArtStat>
  <Days>
    <Day>
      <Date>2022-10-13</Date>
      <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
      <QtyOut>0</QtyOut>
    </Day>
    <Day>
      <Date>2022-10-12</Date>
      <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
      <QtyOut>0</QtyOut>
    </Day>
    <Day>
      <Date>2022-10-11</Date>
      <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
      <QtyOut>5</QtyOut>
     </Day>
     <Day>
       <Date>2022-10-10</Date>
       <QtyIn>0</QtyIn>
       <QtyOut>4</QtyOut>
     </Day>
  </Days>
</ECRArtStat>
  </xsl:param>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is e.g.

```
<Columns>
  <Column type="pastWeek">
    <WeekNo>40</WeekNo>
    <Year>2022</Year>
    <StartDay>2022-10-03</StartDay>
  </Column>
  <Column type="currentWeek">
    <WeekNo>41</WeekNo>
    <Year>2022</Year>
    <StartDay>2022-10-10</StartDay>
    <Day>2022-10-10</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-11</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-12</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-13</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-14</Day>
    <Day>2022-10-15</Day>
  <Sum>9</Sum></Column>
</Columns>
```

Comment: 1st: When I run it, then the result is:
<!--Sum {sum($ArticleStatistics/ECRArticleStatistic/Days/Day[Date = current()/Day]/QtyOut)}-->
--> no calculation, just a comment

2nd: What does match="Column[Day]" means? Match for each Column node which has a Day node?

3rd: What does next-match do?

4th: I need to match for each Day, not for Column, cause I must do something for each Column once and Sum the Day

I do use Saxon HE 9.9.1-8

Comment: With the used `expand-text="yes"`, the text value template works as shown. If you can't or don't want to use it, then use the `select` attribute e.g. `select="sum(..)"` of any element like `xsl:sequence`, `xsl:value-of`, `xsl:comment`. The `Column[Day]` is just an attempt to only search for references where `Day` elements exists, as your input show two `Column` element, where the first doesn't seem to be relevant for the question. `xsl:next-match` is a standard XSLT 3 and 2 way to delegate processing to built-in or lower precedence templates e.g. in this case for the identity transformation.

Comment: But all that part is only used to give a complete example, you said you couldn't get the sum to work, so I showed an example where the sum works. I don't see why you can't match on a `Column`, given your initial `<xsl:for-each select="Day">`, that suggests you want to process the `Day` children of a `Column`.

Comment: Well, of course I must simplify my case...otherwise nobody will understand what the issue is. 
If I use the same function with sum(..) inside a value-of select, then there is an error message: The required item type of the first operand of '/' is node(); the supplied value u"<ECRArticleStatistic CID="4" GID="3..." is an atomic value. Found while atomizing the first argument of fn:sum(), means I have the same error as I  had before...

Comment: Simplified, I have this:
<xsl:template match="Column[Day]">
<xsl:value-of select="sum($ArticleStatistics/ECRArticleStatistic/Days/Day[Date = current()/Day]/QtyOut)"/>
<xsl:next-match />
</xsl:template>
but that gives me the error, cause the current() function does not work
That was my originin question about the current() function

Comment: when I use expand-text="yes", then I have the error:
The required item type of the first operand of '/' is node(); the supplied value u"<ArtStat..." is an atomic value. Found while atomizing the first argument of fn:sum(). I cannot make your solution work here. I use Saxon HE 9.9.1-8

Comment: You said your attempts didn't work without giving details, I have given now two complete, working samples. Try to adapt them to your needs.

Comment: I did implement your example here, and I told you it gives stylesheet compoilation errors here...."The required item type of the first operand of '/' is node(); the supplied value u"<ArtStat..." is an atomic value"

Comment: It is not clear why the code I tested would give you that error. Either you adapted it, then show a minimal but complete XSLT and input sample giving that error.